# Decimal places in annotations of forest plots generated with the metafor package

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor, plot-annotations

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70010987/significant-figures-for-mean-and-sds-in-forest-plot-for-metafor/73702312#73702312) about significant figures displayed in forest plots generated with the metafor package , option `digits` was suggested to specify the number of decimal places for tick mark labels of the x-axis and plot annotations.

Is it possible to specify a different number of decimal places for different parts of the annotation, i.e. 1 decimal for the weights, more than one decimals for the effect sizes, and, if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment. But I think this is a useful feature (showing many digits on the weights is often not that useful, so being able to adjust the number of digits for the weights separately from what is used for the effect size estimates and the x-axis labels makes sense). I have just pushed an update to the development version of metafor that allows you to specify 3 values for `digits`, the first for the annotations, the second for the x-axis label, and the third for the weights. You can install the development version as described here:

https://github.com/wviechtb/metafor#installation